# Reverse eneneering a password for an archive from Armv7 assembly for projet 1200

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse-engineering, armv7

This is my first time ever posting here - please be gentle. I get a lot of useful tips from this site when I search Google for problems unrelated, and it seems like everyone here has a pretty good idea of what's going on.

I am analyzing firmware for a 3d printer and I'm trying to figure out a password that this ecosystem uses for its zip files. I have never touched to assembly so this has proved quite a challenge. I found a section of code that I think should have to get an image from the archive to function. And now I need help with understanding what is it doing to get the files from the encrypted archive. And if there is a way how to quickly search for a piece of code that is decoding the encrypted files and where to look for the password

In the section of code I'm analyzing there is a very obviously named reference to <yo_display_image> which seems that it could be connected to getting that image, but the only place I see the reference to that name is in other functions that need the image to work, nowhere how is it built and obtained.

Here is the section of code that I'm analyzing

```
000311b8 <_ZN16LanderBuildModel24yo_printer_build_a_layerEiPcii>:
   311b8:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
   311bc:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
   311c0:   e24dd010    sub sp, sp, #16
   311c4:   e50b0008    str r0, [fp, #-8]
   311c8:   e50b100c    str r1, [fp, #-12]
   311cc:   e50b2010    str r2, [fp, #-16]
   311d0:   e50b3014    str r3, [fp, #-20]  @ 0xffffffec
   311d4:   e59f00a0    ldr r0, [pc, #160]  @ 3127c <_ZN16LanderBuildModel24yo_printer_build_a_layerEiPcii+0xc4>
   311d8:   e59f10a0    ldr r1, [pc, #160]  @ 31280 <_ZN16LanderBuildModel24yo_printer_build_a_layerEiPcii+0xc8>
   311dc:   e59f209c    ldr r2, [pc, #156]  @ 31280 <_ZN16LanderBuildModel24yo_printer_build_a_layerEiPcii+0xc8>
   311e0:   ebff7712    bl  ee30 <printf@plt>
   311e4:   e51b0010    ldr r0, [fp, #-16]
   311e8:   eb018573    bl  927bc <yo_display_image> 
   311ec:   e51b3014    ldr r3, [fp, #-20]  @ 0xffffffec
   311f0:   e59f208c    ldr r2, [pc, #140]  @ 31284 <_ZN16LanderBuildModel24yo_printer_build_a_layerEiPcii+0xcc>
   311f4:   e0c21293    smull   r1, r2, r3, r2
   311f8:   e1a020c2    asr r2, r2, #1
   311fc:   e1a03fc3    asr r3, r3, #31
   31200:   e0633002    rsb r3, r3, r2
   31204:   e51b0008    ldr r0, [fp, #-8]
   31208:   e3a01000    mov r1, #0
   3120c:   e1a02003    mov r2, r3
   31210:   ebfffdfd    bl  30a0c <_ZN16LanderBuildModel33yo_printer_platform_move_up_microEii>
   31214:   e59f006c    ldr r0, [pc, #108]  @ 31288 <_ZN16LanderBuildModel24yo_printer_build_a_layerEiPcii+0xd0>
   31218:   ebff78e1    bl  f5a4 <usleep@plt>
   3121c:   e59f0068    ldr r0, [pc, #104]  @ 3128c <_ZN16LanderBuildModel24yo_printer_build_a_layerEiPcii+0xd4>
   31220:   e3a01001    mov r1, #1
   31224:   eb0187ae    bl  930e4 <yo_gpio_set>
   31228:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
   3122c:   e3530001    cmp r3, #1
   31230:   ca000001    bgt 3123c <_ZN16LanderBuildModel24yo_printer_build_a_layerEiPcii+0x84>
   31234:   e3a0003c    mov r0, #60 @ 0x3c
   31238:   ebff786d    bl  f3f4 <sleep@plt>
   3123c:   e59b2004    ldr r2, [fp, #4]
   31240:   e1a03002    mov r3, r2
   31244:   e1a03283    lsl r3, r3, #5
   31248:   e0623003    rsb r3, r2, r3
   3124c:   e1a03103    lsl r3, r3, #2
   31250:   e0833002    add r3, r3, r2
   31254:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
   31258:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
   3125c:   ebff78d0    bl  f5a4 <usleep@plt>
   31260:   e59f0024    ldr r0, [pc, #36]   @ 3128c <_ZN16LanderBuildModel24yo_printer_build_a_layerEiPcii+0xd4>
   31264:   e3a01000    mov r1, #0
   31268:   eb01879d    bl  930e4 <yo_gpio_set>
   3126c:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
   31270:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
   31274:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
   31278:   e8bd8800    pop {fp, pc}
   3127c:   00104070    .word   0x00104070
   31280:   0010973c    .word   0x0010973c
   31284:   66666667    .word   0x66666667
   31288:   00061a80    .word   0x00061a80
   3128c:   0001001c    .word   0x0001001c
```

EDIT:
I found the <yo_display_image> function

```
000927bc <yo_display_image>:
   927bc:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
   927c0:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
   927c4:   e24dd010    sub sp, sp, #16
   927c8:   e50b0010    str r0, [fp, #-16]
   927cc:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
   927d0:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
   927d4:   e59f3070    ldr r3, [pc, #112]  @ 9284c <yo_display_image+0x90>
   927d8:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
   927dc:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
   927e0:   0a000003    beq 927f4 <yo_display_image+0x38>
   927e4:   e59f3060    ldr r3, [pc, #96]   @ 9284c <yo_display_image+0x90>
   927e8:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
   927ec:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
   927f0:   ebfdf257    bl  f154 <SDL_FreeSurface@plt>
   927f4:   e24b3008    sub r3, fp, #8
   927f8:   e51b0010    ldr r0, [fp, #-16]
   927fc:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
   92800:   ebffff5f    bl  92584 <yo_display_tool_load_image_to_surface> 
   92804:   e1a02000    mov r2, r0
   92808:   e59f303c    ldr r3, [pc, #60]   @ 9284c <yo_display_image+0x90>
   9280c:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
   92810:   e59f3034    ldr r3, [pc, #52]   @ 9284c <yo_display_image+0x90>
   92814:   e5932000    ldr r2, [r3]
   92818:   e59f302c    ldr r3, [pc, #44]   @ 9284c <yo_display_image+0x90>
   9281c:   e5933004    ldr r3, [r3, #4]
   92820:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
   92824:   e3a01000    mov r1, #0
   92828:   ebffff72    bl  925f8 <yo_display_tool_apply_surface_to_surface>
   9282c:   e59f3018    ldr r3, [pc, #24]   @ 9284c <yo_display_image+0x90>
   92830:   e5933004    ldr r3, [r3, #4]
   92834:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
   92838:   ebfdf0c5    bl  eb54 <SDL_Flip@plt>
   9283c:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
   92840:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
   92844:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
   92848:   e8bd8800    pop {fp, pc}
   9284c:   00168638    .word   0x00168638
```

Comment: The `.word` data after the function is a "literal pool".  Some of them are probably pointers (perhaps into `.rodata`).  Three of the words are loaded early in the function with PC-relative addressing modes (which is the whole point of putting them nearby). e.g. `ldr r0, [pc, #160]` which the disassembler annotated with the actual load address, `3127c`, which gets the value `0x00104070` into `R0` before `bl printf`. So it's a pointer to a format string.  Two of the other .word values look like pointers: 0x0010973c and 0x0001001c so I'd check the file positions corresponding to those addresses.

Comment: What 3D printer, BTW?  If anyone else is trying to reverse engineer the same firmware, including the name will let them find this Q&A.

Comment: (I added the name of the printer to the title)

@PeterCordes I don't really understand what you meant by checking the file positions corresponding to those addresses but when I searched for those addresses in the .so file there were no matches. But during searching for those addresses and analyzing the code blindly I found the function <yo_display_image> I have no idea how it wasn't found by ctrl+f eariler. I added that function to the post and maybe you can find where the password could be in there. Thank you very much for helping me with this problem, you are a lifesaver